# How do I highlight a random word from a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am creating a **drag and drop** word game. This part of the script dynamically creates a table from **12 random words** pulled from the **listOfWords.** I need a word in the table to be highlighted with the given CSS until it is completed to show the user which word to spell. It would then randomly choose another word in the table to spell and so on until all the words are complete....

I have tried various different ways but can't get it working, please help

```
var listOfWords = ["mat", "cat", "dog", "pit", "pot", "fog", "log", "pan", "can", "man", "pin", "gag", "sat", "pat", "tap", "sap", "tag", "gig", "gap", "nag", "sag", "gas", "pig", "dig", "got", "not", "top", "pop", "god", "mog", "cot", "cop", "cap", "cod", "kid", "kit", "get", "pet", "ten", "net", "pen", "peg", "met", "men", "mum", "run", "mug", "cup", "sun", "mud", "rim", "ram", "rat", "rip", "rag", "rug", "rot", "dad", "sad", "dim", "dip", "did", "mam", "map", "nip", "tin", "tan", "nap", "sit", "tip", "pip", "sip", "had", "him", "his", "hot", "hut", "hop", "hum", "hit", "hat", "has", "hug", "but", "big", "bet", "bad", "bad", "bed", "bud", "beg", "bug", "bun", "bus", "bat", "bit", "fit", "fin", "fun", "fig", "fan", "fat", "lap", "lot", "let", "leg", "lit"];

var guesses = {};

var shuffledWords = listOfWords.slice(0).sort(function() {
return 0.5 - Math.random();
}).slice(0, 12);

var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.className = 'tablestyle';
var wordsPerRow = 2;

for (var i = 0; i < shuffledWords.length; i += wordsPerRow) {
var row = document.createElement('tr');

for (var j = i; j < i + wordsPerRow; ++j) {
    var word = shuffledWords[j];
    guesses[word] = [];

    for (var k = 0; k < word.length; ++k) {
        var cell = document.createElement('td');


        $(cell).addClass('drop').attr('data-word', word);
        cell.textContent = word[k];
        // IF FIREFOX USE cell.textContent = word[j]; INSTEAD
        row.appendChild(cell);
        }
   }
    tbl.appendChild(row);
}

document.body.appendChild(tbl);
```

Here is the **CSS** i want to apply to the word needed to spell...

```
.spellword {

    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #176BC9;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px #176BC9;

}
```

I think it would be something along these lines...

```
var wordToSpell = shuffledWords.slice(0).sort(function() {
return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
$("wordToSpell").addClass("spellword");
  }).slice(0,1);
```

I have also tried this, but no joy...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var wordToSpell = [
     <c:forEach var="word" items="${listOfWords}">'${word}', </c:forEach> // JSP : server-side
 ];  
 for (var i = 0; i < wordToSpell.length; i++) {
     $('td').highlight(wordToSpell[i]);
 }
});
```

Comment: In the title? He posted what he's tried and doesn't work.

Comment: Your shuffle algorithm is [problematic](http://www.robweir.com/blog/2010/02/microsoft-random-browser-ballot.html).  You might want to try some version of the [Fischer-Yates algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes you can just change the name of the button and use .mousedown, its better

```
$('.minibutton').mousedown(function() {
    $('td').removeClass('spellword'); 
    var randomWord = shuffledWords.sort(
        function() {
            return 0.8 - Math.random(); 
         }
     )[0]; 

     $('td[data-word="' + randomWord + '"]').addClass('spellword'); 
});
```

Comment: And your edit history is preserved, so editing to change variable names doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

A jquery solution could be as follows:

```
$('#pickNext').click(function(){
    // remove the class from all td's
    $('td').removeClass('spellword');
    // pick a random word
    var rndWord = shuffledWords.sort(function() {  return 0.5 - Math.random(); })[0];
    // apply class to all cells containing a letter from that word
    $('td[data-word="' + rndWord + '"]').addClass('spellword');
});
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/zWfm3/1/

Comment: This is what I mean, but instead of a button I just want it to randomize when it is run and when that word is spelt, go to the next and so on... Thanks @Jamiec

Comment: I have another button called minibutton that i want to apply it to that also plays sound can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So when you create the tree you could add a class to each  that is the word:

```
$(cell).addClass(word)
```

then to highlight it just do:

```
$(word).addClass("spellword");
```